# Передать массив из js в php и сохранить его в БД

Tags: javascript, php

Как это сделать?

```
var X = document.getElementsByName('pred_neud__00')
var z = [[9,2,5], [3,4,5]];

console.log(z)
var stringData = JSON.stringify( z );
console.log(stringData)

document.getElementById('submit_in').onclick = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../func.php",
        data: {data: stringData},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
}
```

Вот такой код у меня в js

Как его принять и обработать в PHP?

```
$object = print_r($_GET['data']);
```

Вот такой код в PHP, но он возвращает N.
Если делаю так:

```
$rem = json_decode($object);
```

Возвращает 1

Comment: Изучайте PHP, а после изучения напишите свой ответ. И вам польза, и нам не нужно тратить время на разъяснения базовых основ, которые можно найти и изучить самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.
Я недавно изучаю PHP и сейчас пытаюсь разобраться с этим моментом. Нашел варианты решения, но у меня почему тоне получается. Был бы Очень признателен за практическую помощь.
Дополнил вопрос кодом PHP/

Comment: var_dump($_REQUEST) глянь, там будет всё https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.request.php, - и $object = $_GET['data'];